# Why does create-react-app adds specific version of "react-scripts" such as "2.1.3"?

Tags: create-react-app

`npm list -g create-react-app`

`# 2.1.3`

`npx create-react-app blah` and `blach/package.json` will be like

```js
# package.json 
{
  "name": "blah",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.3" # <==== why no ^ here
  },
```

SO asks me to add some more as "plain text" is less than pasted package.json bits. Therefore these lines are just to make that algorithm happy.

Answer (score 0):

It's just the current version of `create-react-app`, see https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/releases

You can upgrade to the latest version with: `npm install react-scripts@latest`

Comment: Not sure if my question was clear, the recent vulnerability did make me ask but why does latest version still uses "specific" rather than "^eual_or_bigger" version without the `caret`?

I will update the question with the CRA version.